# Environment that counts words inside

Tags: environments, word-count

How can I create the environment that could count words inside itself? More specifically, I want to write an enviroment called "assignment" such that the code

```
\begin{assignment}
Some words here.
\end{assignment}
```

will result in "Some words here." in the text and, say, "3 words" in a margin paragraph.

I tried searching for that, but found only (external) tools to count words in the entire document, while I need to do this with LaTeX code and for a single environment (possibly repeated several times in a document).

Comment: My "obligatory latex3 answer"-sense is tingling.

Comment: This is a soluion for ConTeXt, maybe it can be adapted to LaTeX, as well: [Dynamically count and return number of words in a section](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44647/5245)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about counting white spaces? This seems easier to implement.

Here is a simple implement. You can improve it to deal with more complex texts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begingroup
\lccode`\~=`\ %
\lowercase{%
  \gdef\assignment{\setcounter{word}{0}%
    \catcode`~=\active
    \def~{\space\stepcounter{word}}}}%
\endgroup
\newcounter{word}
\def\endassignment{\stepcounter{word}%
  \marginpar{\arabic{word} words}}
\begin{document}

\begin{assignment}
Here are some words.
\end{assignment}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

Here's an environment that counts word inside. It uses the [`xesearch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xesearch) package, so it requires XeLaTeX.

Searching is kept local to the environment, that's why it's defined inside.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xesearch}
\newcounter{words}
\newenvironment{assignment}{%
  \setcounter{words}{0}
  \SearchList!{wordcount}{\stepcounter{words}}
    {a?,b?,c?,d?,e?,f?,g?,h?,i?,j?,k?,l?,m?,
    n?,o?,p?,q?,r?,s?,t?,u?,v?,w?,x?,y?,z?}
  \UndoBoundary{'}
  \SearchOrder{p;}}{%
  \StopSearching
  \marginpar{\arabic{words} words}}
\begin{document}
\begin{assignment}
Here are a few words for a word count demonstration.
\end{assignment}
\end{document}
```

[image: word count example]

Comment: I have been using this environment without problem until suddenly  getting a `Tex capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=50000]`.  I think it might be related to the fact that every page is generating an `Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active` error.

Comment: This environment doesn't seem to work with the version of XeLaTeX packaged in TeXLive 2016.  Can anyone update it for the recent changes?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324151/wordcount-with-xesearch-errors contains the relevant fix for current XeLaTeX.