# print word count

Tags: counters, word-count

The journal I am submitting to requires a count of the words on the title page. I can of course run `texcount` on the `.tex` document and put the number in, but it seems that I should be able to automate this.

For tables and figures (which are also required), I can simply use the `totcount` package. Is there something equivalent for words? Or can I store the output of `texcount` in such a way that I can call it on a subsequent `pdflatex` run?

Comment: This is similar in many ways to the request at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44618/dynamically-count-and-return-number-of-words-in-a-section. I can't see how to adopt this directly, however.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the solution using [bashful](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bashful).  Note that you need to run `latex` or `pdflatex` using `-shell-escape` option

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bashful}
\pagestyle{empty}
\bash
texcount -sum -1 tmp.tex
\END
\begin{document}    
This file has \emph{\bashStdout} words.
\end{document}
```

[image]:

Comment: I combined your `texcount` syntax with the macro supplied by Jake on the other question, and it works wonderfully. Yours didn't work because of \bashStdout is not recognized as a control statement. But thanks for helping me with the `texcount` syntax!

Comment: You probably need to upgrade bashful to get `\bashStdout` to work

Comment: I don't suppose that there is a way to pass the name of the document to texcount automatically? The macro from the other question uses \jobname, but when I tried that here it didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution that does not require an external package:

```
 \makeatletter\@@input|"echo `texcount -1 manuscript.tex`| cut -c1-4"\makeatother
```

The `cut` command assumes a four digit number and could be parsed more elegantly.

This command requires `--shell-escape` when compiling, as in:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape myfile.tex
```

Comment: I prefer this solution respect to the first one. However, when I use it, it produces an unwanted white space after the four digit number. I worked around that using `\hspace{-.5ex}` but maybe it depends on the parsing of `texcount`'s output

Comment: BTW, it can be improved as following:
`\makeatletter\@@input|"echo `texcount -q -1 -merge \jobname.tex`| cut -c1-4"\makeatother`

Comment: Another improvement would be `cut -d+ -f1` instead of `cut -c1-4` to make the script work regardless of the number of words in the document (`-d+` uses `+` as field delimiter, `-f1` orders `cut` to output only the first field).