# Print a total word count that sums up the number of words, tables, and figures

Tags: word-count

The journal I am submitting to requires a total word count on the title page.  My question is more like an extension to [Greg's previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49153/print-word-count).  The journal states that a table/figure is counted as 250 words, and the total word count -- which is essentially word count + figure count * 250 + table count * 250 -- cannot exceed a certain number.

From Greg's solution, I was able to print the three counts using `texcount` and `totcount`:

```
\newcommand\wordcount{
    \immediate\write18{texcount -sum -1 \jobname.tex > count.txt} \input{count.txt}}
\usepackage{totcount}
    \regtotcounter{table}   %count tables
    \regtotcounter{figure}  %count figures

Word Count: \wordcount words + \total{figure} figure(s) + \total{table} table(s) = ?? words
```

My question is, in LaTeX, how do I calculate the total word count (??) using the three counts and print it on my title page?

PS. I am new to LaTeX (and `TeX.SX`) so any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\numexpr` and other commands to calculate the multiplication.

However, just inputing `count.txt` does not make the number available for computation. I stored the number to a counter instead.

The command `\totalwordcount` computes the number of words from the `\wordcount` command and adds the table/figure word amount then, finally the counter value is printed. Afterwards the command is redefined to provide only the counter value, no computations are done in the end.

```
\documentclass{article}


\newread\somefile
\usepackage{xparse}


\newcounter{totalwordcounter}
\newcounter{wordcounter}
\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\wordcount}{s}{%
  \immediate\write18{texcount -sum -1 \jobname.tex > count.txt}%
  \immediate\openin\somefile=count.txt%
  \read\somefile to \@@localdummy%
  \immediate\closein\somefile%
  \setcounter{wordcounter}{\@@localdummy}%
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{%
  \@@localdummy%   print only if not starred version
  }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{table}   %count tables
\regtotcounter{figure}  %count figures


\newcommand{\numberofwordsthejournalthinksforafigure}{250}
\newcommand{\numberofwordsthejournalthinksforatable}{250}

\newcommand{\totalwordcount}{%
\wordcount*% Just get the number, don't print it
\setcounter{totalwordcounter}{\value{wordcounter}}%
\addtocounter{totalwordcounter}{\numexpr\numberofwordsthejournalthinksforafigure*\totvalue{figure}}%
\addtocounter{totalwordcounter}{\numexpr\numberofwordsthejournalthinksforatable*\totvalue{table}} % 
\number\value{totalwordcounter}% Output the number: Do not use \thetotalwordcounter here!
\renewcommand{\totalwordcount}{\number\value{totalwordcounter}}% Prevent the call again, otherwise the figure/table counter would be added again. 
}



\setcounter{figure}{100}
\setcounter{table}{10}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem % 12 words

Word Count: \wordcount words + \total{figure} figure(s) + \total{table} table(s) = \totalwordcount~words

\end{document}
```

[image]