# Total word count using texcount

Tags: sharelatex, overleaf, texcount

This question is an extension of [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255940/print-a-total-word-count-that-sums-up-the-number-of-words-tables-and-figures), although the answer to that question worked well in TeX-Studio, it does not work [in Overleaf v2](https://v2.overleaf.com/read/zqdxkyftbmxr), which was primarily the Shareletax interface).  It seems that `\wordcount` failed to return a number.

My first question is: why the original answer does not work in Overleaf?

On the other hand, I tried the minimum example below and it was able to return the correct word count in [Overleaf v2](https://v2.overleaf.com/read/nscjztxytbrq).  My second question is, can I somehow combine these 2 sets of codes and successfully automate total word count in Overleaf v2?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\quickwordcount}[1]{%
  \immediate\write18{texcount -1 -sum -merge #1.tex > #1-words}%
  \input{#1-words}words%
}
\begin{document}
  There are \quickwordcount{main} in this article.
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you click on the Overleaf menu button (or ShareLaTeX's menu button on the upper left), there is already a "Word count" option which also uses texcount. If you prefer defining `\quickwordcount` to set some texcount parameters: the previous solution with `\jobname` no longer works well, because ShareLaTeX/Overleaf v2 sets the `\jobname` to `output`.

Comment: Thanks LianTze.  Is there a way I can assign `\input{#1-words}` as a variable in LaTeX and use it to calculate the final word count?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click on the Overleaf menu button (or ShareLaTeX's menu button on the upper left), there is already a "Word count" option which also uses texcount. If you prefer defining `\quickwordcount` to set some texcount parameters: the previous solution with `\jobname` no longer works well, because ShareLaTeX/Overleaf v2 sets the `\jobname` to `output`.

The following works for me:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\quickwordcount}[1]{%
  \immediate\write18{texcount -1 -sum -merge #1.tex > #1-words}%
  \immediate\openin\somefile=#1-words%
  \read\somefile to \@@localdummy%
  \immediate\closein\somefile%
  \setcounter{wordcounter}{\@@localdummy}%
  \@@localdummy%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Total number of words: \quickwordcount{paper} 
(where "paper.tex" is the name of the tex file)
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work. Is this code still working with the current Overleaf? If so, can you make it into a MWE?

Comment: I have managed to get it working using the code from [this Overleaf page](https://pt.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Is_there_a_way_to_run_a_word_count_that_doesn%27t_include_LaTeX_commands%3F#Run_texcount_with_custom_parameters).