# Print character count

Tags: counters, word-count, count, bashful

[Background inspiration and code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49162/113317):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bashful}
\pagestyle{empty}
\bash
texcount -sum -1 tmp.tex
\END
\begin{document}
%here is a front page and a table of contents
%Counted characters: \bashStdout}
%START CHARACTER COUNTING
This file has \emph{\bashStdout} words.
%END COUNTING CHARACTERS
\end{document}
```

**Problems**

- It shall count the characters and not the words.
- It shall only count the characters in one specific region -- and only count like a Microsoft Word would do it.
- It shall print the number above the counted region.

Comment: Have you tried `texcount -char -sum -1 tmp.tex`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thx! But how do count characters in just a specific region? It shall not count the toc or the references, nor the front page, nothing but the very running text (+foodnotes). The fooder / header shall not be counted either.

Comment: @RalphGottlieb [TeXcount](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/) will count text, headers, other text (footnotes, captions, ...), etc. separately, and it is possible to set rules for how text in different macros/environments is counted. For a quick test, you can try the [web service](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/online.php) with Language/word typesset to Letters. Only beware that TeXcount does not count spaces, and by default not punctuation (can be tweaked).