# Count words in LaTeX with inclusion in LaTeX build process

Tags: tex-core, word-count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamically count and return number of words in a section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44618/dynamically-count-and-return-number-of-words-in-a-section)

I'd like to include the word count of my LaTeX document in the document itself and not have to worry about updating it. All solutions I've found so far involve external scripts.

Yes, I could write a build file that counts the words, modifies the TeX file, and then builds the PDF. However, my IDE builds everythings itself so that I don't have access to the build process. Can't that be done in pure TeX / LaTeX?

Comment: Interesting question. One would think that this should be possible, but I can't find any solutions out there, and my TeX-fu is too weak to attempt to write it.

Comment: With `-shell-escape` you could run something like [`latexcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/latexcount) during compilation.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great pointer! I'll try some things sometime during the weekend.

Comment: Great, that worked. What's the thing to do now, should I answer the question myself? Werner, you could've created an answer instead of a comment, right?