# wordcount by section when sections were formally known as chapter

Tags: article, books, texcount

I have a wordcount macro I use to keep track of word numbers for each chapter of a `book`. Each chapter is written in a separate file which I `input` from my master file.  When I work on a single chapter, I compile the text in a smaller master file of the `article` class, which results in a much faster compilation time. In the `book`, chapters are naturally defined by the `\chapter{}` command. In order to compile a single chapter with the `article` class, I map the `\chapter` command to `\section` in the preamble. Unfortunately, this breaks my wordcount macro. This has something to do with the macro looking for chapters that aren't there. The truth is I don't understand what `grep` and `sed` are doing.

Suggestions for a hack welcome. I probably need a more comprehensive way to redefine the `\chapter` command than the simple `\let` I have used. My `wordcount` macro for the `article` class (extracted from the **MWE**) is the following:

```
\newcommand\wordcount{
    \immediate\write18{texcount -sub=section \jobname.tex  | grep "Section" | sed -e 's/+.*//' | sed -n \thesection p > 'wordcount.log'}
\marginpar{[\input{wordcount.log}words]}}
```

If I manually replace each instance of `\chapter` by `\section`, the wordcount macro works. But it breaks when I redefine chapters to be sections with this shortcut:

```
\let\chapter\section
```

**MWE** to be compiled with `shell-escape` enabled (I use `XeLaTeX`)

```
% !TeX document-id = {965bf974-53c7-4aa7-bc9b-fb76fa6b22ae}
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///xelatex/[--shell-escape]
\documentclass{article}
\let\chapter\section % article class does not understand the \chapter command
\newcommand\wordcount{
    \immediate\write18{texcount -sub=section \jobname.tex  | grep "Section" | sed -e 's/+.*//' | sed -n \thesection p > 'wordcount.log'}
\marginpar{[\input{wordcount.log}words]}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.

\wordcount

\chapter{Main Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.

\wordcount

\chapter{Conclusion}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. 

\wordcount

\end{document}
```

[image]

When I manually replace `\chapter` by `\section`, it looks like this:

[image]

Side note: I tried to use the `blindtext` package to make the code of the **MWE** more succinct, but that does not work with the wordcount macro even with standard `\section` commands.

This is problably where I got my wordcount macro:
[Dynamically count and return number of words in a section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44618/dynamically-count-and-return-number-of-words-in-a-section?rq=1), with other useful exchanges here:
[Is there any way to do a correct word count of a LaTeX document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534/is-there-any-way-to-do-a-correct-word-count-of-a-latex-document)

It wasn't too hard to adapt the `wordcount` macro for the `book` class:

```
\newcommand\wordcount{
    \immediate\write18{texcount -sub=section \jobname.tex  | grep "Chapter" | sed -e 's/+.*//' | sed -n \thechapter p > 'wordcount.log'}
\marginpar{[\input{wordcount.log}words]}}
```

Comment: `\blindtext` etc. can't work because the words are hidden in the macro, in my opinion

Comment: `grep` searches for expressions, `sed`is for replacing them. You should try to run your `texcount` first on the command line to make it work, then wrap it up in a macro. The basic error is `Section` -- you need `Chapter`, since `texcount` prints `Chapter` in the output

Comment: PatrickT -- I forgot to mention: You must replace `sub=chapter`, since `texcount` looks for this sub then. Renaming the macro does not help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the improved version at the end of this post (2016/4/23)

The situation is a little more complicated than just renaming `\chapter` etc with a `\let\chapter\section` statement.

- `texcount` looks for real sectioning units, `sub=section` or `sub=chapter` --> `\chapter` needs `sub=chapter`
- If chapters are found, the output of `texcount is something like

> ```
> File: wordcountchapters.tex
> Encoding: ascii
> Words in text: 409
> Words in headers: 4
> Words outside text (captions, etc.): 0
> Number of headers: 3
> Number of floats/tables/figures: 0
> Number of math inlines: 0
> Number of math displayed: 0
> Subcounts:
>   text+headers+captions (#headers/#floats/#inlines/#displayed)
>   114+1+0 (1/0/0/0) Chapter: Introduction
>   228+2+0 (1/0/0/0) Chapter: Main Section
>   67+1+0 (1/0/0/0) Chapter: Conclusion
> ```

This means, `grep` must look for `Chapter`, not `Section`

→ change to "Chapter" or better `grep -i "chapter"` (ignoring case)

- The next line replaces `+` etc. and is caught with `\thesection`, i.e. number of the section (or chapter). This must be replaced with some trickier statement
  `\the\numexpr\value{chapter}` (to get the correct value)

To make this work, a fake counter `\let\c@chapter\c@section` is introduced -- this way, the `chapter` counter has the same values like the `section` counter

I've put it all together below: the macro uses an optional argument that defaults to `chapter`. In other setups, use `\wordcount[section]`.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\chapter\section % article class does not understand the \chapter command
\makeatletter
\let\c@chapter\c@section % fake counter
\makeatother

\newcommand\wordcount[1][chapter]{%
  \immediate\write18{texcount -sub=#1 \jobname.tex  | grep -i "#1" | sed -e 's/+.*//' | sed -n \the\numexpr\value{#1}+1 p > 'wordcount.log'}%
  \marginpar{[\input{wordcount.log}words]}}

\begin{document}


\chapter{Introduction} 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.

\wordcount

\chapter{Main Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.

\wordcount

\chapter{Conclusion}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. 

\wordcount

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Improved version**

I've expanded the solution above to be configurable with a single command, `\prepareforwordcount` and `\presetkeys{wc}{sub=chapter}{}` (`\presetkeys` is from the `xkeyval` package)

The `\prepareforwordcount` sets the `\chapter` command etc. and `\wordcount` uses the preset value of the `sub=...` entry.

Due to a `flaw` of the shell - script, the `\jobname` mustn't contain the name of the sub unit, if `chapter` is requested, don't use a jobname with 'chapter' in it (`texcount` prints the file name and this will contain `chapter`, which in turn is counted by `grep` then).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key{wc}{sub}[section]{%
  \gdef\kvwc@sub{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\prepareforwordcount}[1][]{%
  \setkeys{wc}{#1}%
  \@ifundefined{\kvwc@sub}{%  e.g does \chapter exist?
    \expandafter\let\csname \kvwc@sub\endcsname\section%
    \expandafter\let\csname c@\kvwc@sub\endcsname\c@section% Generate a fake counter to be the same as \c@section 
  }{%
    % Nothing to be done!
  }%
}

\newcommand\wordcount[1][]{%
  \setkeys{wc}{#1}%
  \immediate\write18{texcount -sub='\kvwc@sub' \jobname.tex  | grep -i "\kvwc@sub" | sed -e 's/+.*//' | sed -n \the\numexpr\value{\kvwc@sub} p > 'wordcount.log'}%
  \marginpar{[\input{wordcount.log}words]}}

\makeatother

\presetkeys{wc}{sub=chapter}{}

\prepareforwordcount





\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction} 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.

\wordcount

\chapter{Main Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.

\wordcount

\chapter{Conclusion}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. 

\wordcount

\end{document}
```

Comment: @PatrickT: I've updated some minutes ago, with a better version -- the proof that it works can be seen in the screenshot -- however, there's a tiny issue I've to solve...

Comment: I'll return to this later on! It's late here

Comment: Your explanations are very useful. I'm sure I can make it work on my setup sooner or later! (I have the latest texlive, updated last week)

Comment: @PatrickT: It works with `xelatex --shell-escape` and `pdflatex --shell-escape`

Comment: @PatrickT: I've updated my solution

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second, improved version doesn't work for me either. Something on my setup must be interfering...

Comment: @PatrickT: Apparently, yes

Comment: @PatrickT: Perhaps you should give more details about your setup (you may write a mail (see the contact address on my profile page)

Comment: For the record, the problem was caused by the presence of invisible "invalid characters".

Answer (score 1):

**Christian Hupfer** has answered my question and provided great explanations of the function of different parts of the wordcount macro I was using, and reasons why it wasn't working after I had redefined the `\chapter` command. Here I want to show an alternative approach I have since discovered: it relies on the package `xesearch` instead of the `texcount` program. It does not require `shell-escape`, but it does require `XeLaTeX`.

The solutions below are based on the `xesearch` manual (c.f. ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/macros/xetex/generic/xesearch/xesearch.pdf).

**Example 1**

The `wordcount` command prints the word count in the margin, on the right of where the command is placed. The word count is cumulative. In the other examples explored further down, the word counter is non-cumulative.

```
% !TeX document-id = {965bf974-53c7-4aa7-bc9b-fb76fa6b22ae}
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///xelatex/[--shell-escape]
\documentclass{article}
\let\chapter\section % article class does not understand the \chapter command
\usepackage{xesearch}
\newcount\wordcounter
\let\shownumber\relax
\SearchList!{wordcounter}{\global\advance\wordcounter1\shownumber{}}
{a?,b?,c?,d?,e?,f?,g?,h?,i?,j?,k?,l?,m?,n?,o?,p?,q?,r?,s?,t?,u?,v?,w?,x?,y?,z?}
\UndoBoundary{'}
\SearchOrder{p;}
\newcommand{\wordcount}{
    \marginpar{~~[\expandafter\the\csname wordcounter\endcsname\ words]}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction} 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.

\wordcount

\chapter{Main Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.

\wordcount

\chapter{Conclusion}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. 

\wordcount

\end{document}
```

[image]

The macro above gives a cumulative word count. To get a word count per section, the word counter may be reset. I have explored two approaches: provide a command to reset the counter manually and/or reset the counter automatically for each section.

---

**Example 2**

The `countwords` environment delimits the start and end of the word count. The `donotcount{}` command is used to wrap notes and other words that should not be included in the wordcount. No cumulative word count is provided.

```
% !TeX document-id = {965bf974-53c7-4aa7-bc9b-fb76fa6b22ae}
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///xelatex/[--shell-escape]
\documentclass{article}
\let\chapter\section % article class does not understand the \chapter command
\usepackage{xesearch}
\newcounter{wordscounter}
\newenvironment{countwords}{%
    \setcounter{wordscounter}{0}
    \SearchList!{wordcount}{\stepcounter{wordscounter}}
        {a?,b?,c?,d?,e?,f?,g?,h?,i?,j?,k?,l?,m?,
        n?,o?,p?,q?,r?,s?,t?,u?,v?,w?,x?,y?,z?}
    \UndoBoundary{'’-}
    \MakeBoundary{„“‚‘–}
    \SearchOrder{p;}}{%
        \StopSearching
        \marginpar{~[\arabic{wordscounter}~words]} 
}
%%  prevent words in the argument from being included in the word count
\newcommand{\donotcount}[1]{\StopSearching #1\StartSearching}% 

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction} 
\begin{countwords}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.
\end{countwords}

\chapter{Main Section}
\begin{countwords}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.\footnote{\donotcount{The words of this footnote will not be included in the wordcount.}}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.
\end{countwords}

\chapter{Conclusion}
\begin{countwords}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
\end{countwords}

\end{document}
```

---

**Example 3**

The `startwordcount` command initiates the word counter.  The `donotcount` command is used to wrap notes and other words that should not be included in the wordcount. The `footnote` command is redefined such that its content is not included in the word count. The `wordcount` commands prints the current word count in the margin. The `chapter` command, which is not defined in the `article` class, is mapped to the `section` command and automatically resets the wordcount counter.

```
% !TeX document-id = {965bf974-53c7-4aa7-bc9b-fb76fa6b22ae}
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///xelatex/[--shell-escape]
\documentclass{article}
% The article class does not understand the \chapter command
% map \chapter to \section and reset wordcounter each time \chapter is invoked
\newcommand\chapter[2][\DefaultOpt]{%
  \def\DefaultOpt{#2}%
  \section[#1]{#2}\setcounter{wordcounter}{0}%
}
\usepackage{xesearch}% must be compiled with xelatex
\newcounter{wordcounter}% define a word counter
\newcommand\startwordcount{%
    \setcounter{wordcounter}{0}
    \SearchList!{wordcount}{\stepcounter{wordcounter}}
        {a?,b?,c?,d?,e?,f?,g?,h?,i?,j?,k?,l?,m?,
        n?,o?,p?,q?,r?,s?,t?,u?,v?,w?,x?,y?,z?}
    \UndoBoundary{'’-}
    \MakeBoundary{„“‚‘–}
    \SearchOrder{p;}
}
%%  print the wordcount counter in the margin
\newcommand\wordcount{%
    \marginpar{~[\arabic{wordcounter}~words]}%
}
%%  prevent words in the argument from being included in the word count
\newcommand{\donotcount}[1]{\StopSearching #1\StartSearching}% 

%%  redefine the \footnote command to take footnotes out of word count
\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand\footnote[1]{%
\oldfootnote{\donotcount{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\startwordcount

\chapter{Introduction} 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.

\wordcount

\chapter{Main Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.\footnote{\donotcount{The words of this footnote will not be included in the wordcount.}}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.

\wordcount

\chapter{Conclusion}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 

\wordcount

\end{document}
```

This is a screenshot of the second and third examples:

[image]