# Counting words do not appear with texcount (using TeXstudio)

Tags: miktex, word-count, texcount

I am trying to get the words cumber per section using the following lines:

```
\newcommand\wordcount{
    \immediate\write18{texcount -sub=section \jobname.tex  | grep "Section" | sed -e 's/+.*//' | sed -n \thesection p > 'count.txt'}
    (\input{count.txt}words)}
```

as in: [Dynamically count words in chapter and insert word count at start of chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453078/dynamically-count-words-in-chapter-and-insert-word-count-at-start-of-chapter)
or [wordcount by section when sections were formally known as chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305835/wordcount-by-section-when-sections-were-formally-known-as-chapter)

however, the words are not counted. But no error pops up.

In the pdf output it appears:

[image: no words example]

Many thanks in advance for your suggestions

Comment: You need to provide more details. Can you run the instruction from the command line? Is the `count.txt` file produced? What's your OS and TeXcount version? Have you set the `shell-escape` option required for running commands from TeX?

Comment: @EinarRødland the file `count.txt` is not produced. I think that is actually the main issue (besides my lack of computational skills) 

Additional information: 
OS:64-bit version ; TeXcount_3_2. 

The `shell-escape` option was set as in: 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99475/how-to-invoke-latex-with-the-shell-escape-flag-in-texstudio-former-texmakerx

Comment: Try reducing the example, and try to see what's the simplest case that still fails. Eg try running just `texcount -o count.txt \jobname.tex` and see if this still fails. You can also try `echo "test" > count.txt` just to see if it actually runs. I also have some vague memory of some version of TeX that took a different option than `shell-escape`.