# texcount mwe no longer functional after tex system update

Tags: texcount

The following mwe has been discussed in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527602/simplified-texcount-results-display?noredirect=1&lq=1), and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558095/how-to-warn-user-if-not-enough-content-added-to-section-using-texcount).  The mwe no longer works after a system update.  Any guidance on troubleshooting is greatly appreciated.

W10, MikTeX 2.9, TeXWorks, installed Perl 5.30, installed grep, confirm that both are installed, added paths of external scripts to `PATH` through PC or TeXWorks, (both seem like they do the same thing)

The limited debug messages I see in the console are:

```
("C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-p
df.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
\sectioncount=
```

Here is the mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}%
%\usepackage{titlesec} %**** uncomment to see error message


% Compile with  --enable-write18 or --shell-escape options   
\immediate\write18{texcount -char -merge -tex -sum \jobname.tex | grep -i section > \jobname Count.txt} % counts characters
%\immediate\write18{texcount -merge -tex -sum \jobname.tex | grep -i section > \jobname Count.txt} % counts words
\newcommand{\limitcount}{-1}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nameref}

\newcommand{\processCount}{%
 \newread\counts
 \def\zpar{\par}
 \openin\counts=\jobname Count.txt
 \loop
 \read\counts to \sectioncount
 \ifx\sectioncount\zpar\else
 \showcount{\sectioncount}\\
 \fi
 \ifeof\counts
 \else
 \repeat
}

\newcommand*{\showcount}[1]{%
 % e.g. 67+18+0 (1/0/0/0) S[ubs]ection: The first subsection
 \StrBehind{#1}{ection: }[\sectiontitleplusspace]
 \StrGobbleRight{\sectiontitleplusspace}{1}[\sectiontitle]
 \StrBefore{#1}{+}[\thiscount]
 \expandafter\ifcsname\sectiontitle limit\endcsname%
  \renewcommand{\limitcount}{\csname\sectiontitle limit\endcsname}%
 \else%
  \renewcommand{\limitcount}{-1}%
 \fi%
 \sectiontitle:
 {%
  \ifthenelse{\thiscount>\limitcount}{%
   \textcolor{red}{\thiscount/\limitcount}%
   \ifthenelse{\limitcount>-1}{%
    \ (over by \number\numexpr\thiscount-\limitcount\relax)%
   }{}%
  }{%
   \textcolor{green}{\thiscount/\limitcount}%
  }%
 }
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\contentlimit}[1]{%
 \expandafter\newcommand\csname\@currentlabelname limit\endcsname{#1}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section*{Over the Limit}
\contentlimit{5}

This content is over the limt.

\section*{Under the Limit}
\contentlimit{100}

More content, this time under the limit.

%TC:ignore 

% display information on document
\section*{Document analysis}
\processCount

%TC:endignore 

\end{document}
```

**Update:**

I verified that `texcount.pl` was present.
I verified that `texcount.exe` was present.
I verified that the Texworks compiler options included references to the paths corresponding to the above.

Still getting `sectioncount=` as an error.

Comment: in texlive 2020 if I uncomment the titlesec line I get the error that `\limit` is defined, do you not see that error?

Comment: Yes, I get `\limit already defined`.

Comment: That isn't what you say about the log file in the question:-)

Comment: Are you sure that it worked before? I get `\limit already defined` error in texlive 2016,2017,2018,2019,2020

Comment: Yes, have been using it successfully for some time.  I'm sure I'm doing something silly, introduced a reversion.

Comment: @Teepeemm, do you have any thoughts?

Comment: @JohnChris An alternative?? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44618/dynamically-count-and-return-number-of-words-in-a-section/587567#587567

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I can't say I understand your comments.  Any helpful hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible alternative to texcount.

Based on my answer here, [Dynamically count and return number of words in a section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44618/dynamically-count-and-return-number-of-words-in-a-section/587567#587567), this is a pure TeX solution to the problem.  No write-18 required.  I adapted the other solution in several ways.  I tried to match the OP's syntax when possible.  However, one still needs to manually set the start and stop points (`\countem...\endcountem`).  I also now keep a global tabulation of the multiple `countem` environments that arise in the document.

The `countem` environment can span across paragraphs, sections, if needed, even tables, equations, etc.  Of course, it will count the invoking syntax of that stuff (unless you |escape the code| between the designated escape-delimiters).  The only proviso is that you can't apply it to stuff that changes the catcodes of its argument (notably `verbatim`), because the method involves scanning all the tokens in advance...thus, token catcodes are set before the user's macro/environment has a chance to change them.

EDIT: I have added the macro `\disablecountem`, so that when you are happy with the counted-document results, you merely need invoke this at the beginning of your document to restore a normal non-counting compilation (exception: if you employed the code-escape mechanism of `tokcycle` to temporarily bypass counting, you will also have to let the escape token to `\empty`.  This is by default a `|` but can be changed in the code, even to a macro, with `\settcEscapechar{}`).

At the request of the OP's comment, I made a 2nd EDIT to allow, with the declaration `\countspacestrue`, to add the count of spaces **and punctuation** (that is to say, cat-10 and cat-12 tokens) into the letter count.  Look for the 4 lines in the MWE labeled with the comment `NEW!!` to see how this change was implemented.

Even NEWER!  I have added support for `\obeyspaces` in the counting of spaces.  To the Macro directive in `\countem`, I added the line `\ifactivetok\ifnum\numberˋ##1=32\relax\stepcounter{lettercount}\fi`, since `\obeyspaces` works by making the space token active.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}[2021-03-10]
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcounter{wordcount}
\newcounter{lettercount}
\newcounter{wordlimit}
\newif\ifinword
% USER PARAMETERS
\newif\ifrunningcount
\newif\ifsummarycount
\def\limitcolor{red}
\setcounter{wordlimit}{0}
%%
\makeatletter
% \tc@defx is like \def, but expands the replacement text once prior to assignment
\newcommand\addtomacro[2]{\tc@defx#1{#1#2}}
\newcommand\changecolor[1]{\tctestifx{.#1}{}{\addcytoks{\color{#1}{}}%
  \tc@defx\currentcolor{#1}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\dumpword{%
  \addcytoks[1]{\accumword}%
  \ifinword\stepcounter{wordcount}
    \ifrunningcount\addcytoks[x]{$^{\thewordcount,\thelettercount}$}\fi
    \ifnum\thewordcount=\value{wordlimit}\relax\changecolor{\limitcolor}\fi
  \fi%
  \inwordfalse
  \def\accumword{}}
\newcommand\addletter[1]{%
  \tctestifcatnx A#1{\stepcounter{lettercount}\inwordtrue}{\dumpword}%
  \ifcountspaces\tctestifcatnx .#1{\stepcounter{lettercount}}{}\fi% NEW!!
  \addtomacro\accumword{#1}}
\newif\ifcountspaces% NEW!!
\xtokcycleenvironment\countem
  {\addletter{##1}}
  {\dumpword\groupedcytoks{\processtoks{##1}\dumpword\expandafter}\expandafter
    \changecolor\expandafter{\currentcolor}}
  {\dumpword\ifactivetok\ifnum\number`##1=32\relax
    \stepcounter{lettercount}\fi\fi\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\dumpword\ifcountspaces\stepcounter{lettercount}\fi\addcytoks{##1}}% NEW!!
  {\stripgroupingtrue\def\accumword{}\def\currentcolor{.}
    \setcounter{wordcount}{0}\setcounter{lettercount}{0}}
  {\dumpword\retainsum\ifsummarycount\tcafterenv{%
    \par(Wordcount=\thewordcount, Lettercount=\thelettercount)}\fi}

\newcommand\contentlimit[1]{\setcounter{wordlimit}{#1}}

\newcounter{globalwordcount}
\newcounter{globallettercount}
\newcommand\retainsum{%
  \addtocounter{globalwordcount}{\thewordcount}%
  \addtocounter{globallettercount}{\thelettercount}%
}

\newcommand\processCount{\ifnum\thegloballettercount>0%
  \par Global Wordcount=\theglobalwordcount\\
  Global Lettercount=\thegloballettercount
\fi}

\newcommand\disablecountem{\let\countem\empty\let\endcountem\empty}

\begin{document}
%\disablecountem% TO TURN OFF COUNTING, WITHOUT CHANGING DOCUMENT
\section*{Over the Limit}

\contentlimit{5}\countem
This content is over the limit.
\endcountem

\section*{Over the Limit with running count shown}

\contentlimit{5}\runningcounttrue\countem
This content is also somewhat over the limit.
\endcountem\runningcountfalse

\section*{Under the Limit with summary count shown}

\contentlimit{100}\summarycounttrue\countem
More content, this time under the limit.
\endcountem

\section*{Example of also counting spaces and punctuation}

\countspacestrue% NEW!!
\countem
Obeyspaces     is    off...\endcountem

{\obeyspaces\countem
Obeyspaces     is     on...\endcountem}

\section*{Document analysis}
\processCount

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant.  Thoughts on a switch to toggle between considering spaces to not considering spaces?

Comment: @JohnChris I presume you mean to count them as characters.  I think that would be easy.  Let me have a look.

Comment: @JohnChris If one creates `\newif\ifcountspaces` and sets the fourth argument of the `\countem` definition to `{\dumpword\ifcountspaces\stepcounter{lettercount}\fi\addcytoks{##1}}`, then spaces are counted when `\countspacestrue` is declared.  However, punctuation is still not counted, since the `\addletter` macro screens for catcode 11.  However, if this line were added to the `\addletter` macro, `\ifcountspaces\tctestifcatnx .#1{\stepcounter{lettercount}}{}\fi`, then cat-12 punctuation would be letter-counted as well when `\countspacestrue` was set.

Comment: @JohnChris I have added those changes to the MWE.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes One of best suggestion...heart full congrats....

Comment: Legend.  This post (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527602/simplified-texcount-results-display?noredirect=1&lq=1) contains details about a very convenient method for visualizing the status of the document with respect to meeting character and word sped.

Comment: I created another question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/594539/character-word-counting-implementation-must-handle-externalized-content-called-v) in order to explore the use of this approach with `\input{}` and externalized content.