# Word count and 'TeX capacity exceeded'

Tags: word-count, xesearch

I use this piece of code in the preamble, obtained from [Environment that counts words inside](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10033/environment-that-counts-words-inside/34572#34572):

```
\usepackage{xesearch}
\newcounter{words}
\newenvironment{assignment}{%
  \setcounter{words}{0}
  \SearchList!{wordcount}{\stepcounter{words}}
    {a?,b?,c?,d?,e?,f?,g?,h?,i?,j?,k?,l?,m?,
    n?,o?,p?,q?,r?,s?,t?,u?,v?,w?,x?,y?,z?}
  \UndoBoundary{'}
  \SearchOrder{p;}}{%
  \StopSearching
  \marginpar{\arabic{words} words}}
```

I use this in my main file that includes several chapters.  If I include up to the end chapter 4 (33599 words) then the counting environment works fine.  If I include the next chapter (~6K words) I get the `TeX capacity exceeded` error.  Having tested and excluded all other options it is definitely down to the `assignment` environment reaching a buffer(?) limit at some point over 33.599K words.  I am not sure how to create a MWE for this particular case without sharing my actual work which for obvious reasons I cannot do.

Comment: This may be just too hard for TeX, I don't know.  Is using LuaLaTeX an option?  If yes, you might want to look at this: https://gist.github.com/phi-gamma/2622252 (didn't test, just googled it).

Comment: You can try whether you get the error with lots of automatically generated contents like [this 100k long lipsum text](http://lipsum.lipsum.com/feed/html?amount=100000&what=bytes&start=yes&generate=Generate+Lorem+Ipsum). Then you post and example with a text `PUT 100k OF TEXT HERE` instead of the long text.

Comment: `\blindtext` also takes an optional repetition argument which could be made large enough to trigger the problem.

Comment: Hi DGarside. A tip: if you copy and paste directly the link of the answer in your question the title will appear.

Comment: Can you add the complete error text?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I run the document below as posted I get a save stack error:

```
[30] [31] [32] [33] [34] [35] [36] [37]
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=50000].
```

If I uncomment the two lines marked `%%%%` then it runs to the end

```
Output written on xew33.pdf (84 pages).
```

and reports 51720 words

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xesearch}
\newcounter{words}
\makeatletter

\newenvironment{assignment}{%
%%%%     \endgroup
  \setcounter{words}{0}%
\expandafter\ifx\csname wordcount@xs@searchlist\endcsname\relax
  \let\wordcount@xs@searchlist\undefined
  \SearchList!{wordcount}{\stepcounter{words}}
    {a?,b?,c?,d?,e?,f?,g?,h?,i?,j?,k?,l?,m?,
    n?,o?,p?,q?,r?,s?,t?,u?,v?,w?,x?,y?,z?}
  \UndoBoundary{'}%
  \SearchOrder{p;}%
  \else
   \expandafter\StartSearching
  \fi}{%
  \StopSearching
  \marginpar{\arabic{words} words}%
%%%%     \begingroup\expandafter\def\csname @currenvir\endcsname{assignment}%
}




\begin{document}

\def\a{one two three four five six seven eight nine ten. }
\def\b{red yellow green blue. }
\def\c{apple orange pear banana.}
\def\d{\a\a\b\b\c\a\b\c\c\b\b}
\def\e{\d\d\par\a\a\b\d\d\b\b\c\c\a\a\a\a\par}
\def\f{\e\e\a\a\b\b\e\c\d\d\a\c\b\a\e\e}


\begin{assignment}
\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f
\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f
\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f
\end{assignment}

\begin{assignment}
one one two three
\end{assignment}


\begin{assignment}
one two three four five six
\end{assignment}


\end{document}
```

the `document` environment in LaTeX plays a similar trick to use the environment syntax but avoid making a group around the whole document.

Comment: This does calculate for size > 50000 but I do not seem able to have one `assignment` environment follow on immediately after another.  The second environment registers as zero.  Would the way around that be to create `assignment_main` and `assignment_bibliography` environments?

Comment: code updated to re-use the existing search structure seems to get the right answer on a couple of smaller lists at the end, see posted image

Comment: It seems that your code edit removed the `%%%%` markings that you mention in the body of your answer.  Was that intentional?