# wordcount with xesearch errors

Tags: xetex, word-count, xesearch

I'm using some code I found here on stackexchange to count words in a LaTeX document. I'm using TeXLive on a Mac and using XeLateX to produce the pdf document. It produces a pdf, but with an error message, and longer documents fail to produce the correct pdf.

Here's a minimal document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xesearch}
\newcounter{words}
\newenvironment{wordcount}{%
\setcounter{words}{0}
\SearchList!{wordcount}{\stepcounter{words}}
    {a?,b?,c?,d?,e?,f?,g?,h?,i?,j?,k?,l?,m?,
    n?,o?,p?,q?,r?,s?,t?,u?,v?,w?,x?,y?,z?}
\UndoBoundary{'’-}
\MakeBoundary{„“‚‘–}
\SearchOrder{p;}}{%
\StopSearching}

\begin{document}
\begin{wordcount}

Here are some words. 
Here are some more words.

\end{wordcount}
\end{document}
```

Here's the error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<XeTeXinterchartoks> \xdef \xs@String {\xs@String
e}
l.20 Her
e are some words.
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I have XeTeX version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016), and the most recent xesearch version available in the TeXLive utility (0.1). This worked fine when I was using Tex Live 2014 version, but so many things have been updated now I don't know where to start figuring out what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version of XeTeX has increased the number of character classes to 4096, but `xesearch` still assumes the upper bound is 255 instead of 4095.

You have to redo the initializations.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xesearch}

\makeatletter
\chardef\xs@NatDel=\e@alloc@intercharclass@top
\chardef\xs@lrDel=\numexpr\e@alloc@intercharclass@top-1\relax
\chardef\xs@Classes=\numexpr\e@alloc@intercharclass@top-2\relax
\XeTeXinterchartoks\xs@lrDel\xs@Classless={\xs@LearnLetter}
\XeTeXinterchartoks\xs@NatDel\xs@Classless={\xs@LearnLetter}
\XeTeXinterchartoks\xs@NatDel\xs@lrDel{\xs@EndString}
\xs@MakeDel\{\}.,;:!?[()]-'`\xs@end
\makeatother

\newcounter{words}
\newenvironment{wordcount}{%
\setcounter{words}{0}
\SearchList!{wordcount}{\stepcounter{words}}
    {a?,b?,c?,d?,e?,f?,g?,h?,i?,j?,k?,l?,m?,
    n?,o?,p?,q?,r?,s?,t?,u?,v?,w?,x?,y?,z?}
\UndoBoundary{'’-}
\MakeBoundary{„“‚‘–}
\SearchOrder{p;}}{%
\StopSearching}

\begin{document}
\begin{wordcount}

Here are some words. 
Here are some more words.

\end{wordcount}

Number of words: \thewords

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you find `\e@alloc@intercharclass@top` to be undefined, update your TeX distribution.

Comment: This works for the example document, but not for my actual document - there I get a "! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000]" error. I've tried to combine your answer with [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99559/word-count-and-tex-capacity-exceeded) solution to that problem, but I still get the same error. My document is not that big - maybe 3000 words.

Actually even if I comment out the wordcount part and just have the reinitialisations at the top, I get the "capacity exceeded" error with my actual document. Any suggestions? Should I open a new question?

Comment: @Liz That message can be due to some infinite recursion. It's quite difficult to say more without a real example.

Comment: I can't post my actual document, and I don't get the same error using the example text given in the solution I linked above. Do you have any idea what could cause an infinite recursion or what might solve it?

Comment: @Liz Sorry, no idea.