# Calculate percentage of quotes in a latex document?

Tags: statistics, quotation, extract, percentage

I need to figure out how many percent of the text in my latex document which consists of quotes (in block quotes, particularly). I have wrapped all quotes in the block quotes command:

```
\begin{quote}
\end{quote}
```

Is there any tool which would easily allow me to either:

1. Calculate the percentage directly, or
2. Extract all content within the block quotes command, and also (in a
   separate output) extract all content which is outside of the block
   quotes command. So that I can input both texts into an online word
   counter, and calculate the percentage from comparing the resulting
   amount of words.

I am using Overleaf, so it's limited what packages I can run, but I think it can run most.

Comment: It would be a nice programming exercise for e.g. Python. Would running a Python Script be okay for you?

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen Yeah, it would be, but I'd rather not bother to fiddle with it. I was able to find a neat and quick LaTeX solution though. See my answer.

Comment: `texcount` is able to count words of delimited parts of the text, as well as text of some common LaTeX structures. See  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277734/11604

Comment: @Fran Yup, that was the one I ended up using. I found the online service, and linked it in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to use the [extract](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/extract) package to get just the quotes out in a separate tex document:

```
% To extract all block quotes to a separate quotes.txt file, downloadable in the bottom of the "log and output files" page in Overleaf
\usepackage[active,generate=quotes,extract-env={quote}]{extract}
```

Then I was able to use the LaTeX word counter found here:

https://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/online.php

Running it first on the original file, and then on the `quotes.tex` file, and compare the word counts.