# Disable Command (output nothing)

Tags: citing

I need to count the words of my document without citations.

E.g. this needs to be 3 words.

> This is text (MySource and AnotherSource, 2020).

My idea was to override all `\parencite` and `\parencites` commands to simply output nothing by:

```
\renewcommand{\parencite}[2][]{}
\renewcommand{\parencites}[xxx][]{}
```

I tried multiple ways and combinations with different argument numbers but could not get no output. Especially, for `\parencites`, I do not even know the number of arguments I need to put in.

How can I just disable it that the example above will be

> This is text

Comment: Have you used texcount?  Most probably each bibkey in citation  commands will be counted  as a single word, so if you know the numer of cites, is simply discount that number. Another option is mark each cite as [text to be ignored by texcount](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277734/11604), but I am not sure if that worth it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the hint. I can estimate the citations, that might be a fallback option and try your approach. I thought there might be a clean and accurate way. Marking them is not an option. I have about 200 pages and 15 pages of cited papers.