# word count function

Tags: word-count, count

how to use "Words: \quickwordcount" or word counting function with below structure at the main.tex?
It could be another tex like wordcount.tex .

Thanks in advance.

```
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
\newgeometry{margin=1in}

\title {ABC} 
\author{ABC}

\date{February 28, 2023}

% -------------------- Title page -------------------- %
%TC:ignore
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

%TC:endignore

\input{body/abstract}
\input{body/keywords}

\clearpage

\singlespacing

\input{body/introduction}
\input{body/motive}
\input{body/localization_mechanism}
\input{body/case_selection}
\input{body/case_study}
\input{body/conclusion}

\clearpage
% \bibliographystyle{chicago}
\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277734/11604) help?

Comment: If the document is very long, consisting of mostly ordinary text, then it might be easier to use the `wc` on command line (Linux, Mac). It would also count the TeX code, but unless you need the exact number of words, you could guess the difference. Also, at least in English, a common way to count words is to divide the character count (including spaces) by 6. That is for the purpose of paper-book publishing.

Comment: What is the purpose of your word count? Are you submitting an article with a limited number of words or number of pages, or ... ? What is a word; a mathematical expression, a graphic, contents of a section tiltle, ... ? Take an arbitrary page, count the number of (what you consider to be) words and multiply by the number of pages, Most times folk want the number of words in order to estimate the overall space taken up in their system doing whatever they do. It is very rare that anyone actually counts the number of words, they use an estimate based on words per page and number of pages.