# Count words separated with comma in macro

Tags: macros, word-count

I need to count number of words in a macro defined as follow:

```
\def\columnNames{MATRIX, METHODA, METHODB}
```

I manually set number of words as follow:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\numberOfColumns{3}
```

I need an automatic way to find number of words in a macro. The list is separated with commas ",".

I have found several solutions ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44618/dynamically-count-and-return-number-of-words-in-a-section),[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10033/environment-that-counts-words-inside),...). However, I was not able to adapt to my situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 'word count' element here is not important: all you require is a method to find the 'length' of a comma-separated list. That's relatively easy to do, but as `expl3` provides a pre-defined solution I'd use that approach

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \commalistlength \clist_count:N
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}
\def\columnNames{MATRIX, METHODA, METHODB}
\pgfmathsetmacro\numberOfColumns{\commalistlength{\columnNames}}
\show\numberOfColumns
\end{document}
```