# Adding Non-breaking space after single character in text mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, verbatim, text-mode

Is it possible in LaTeX (2e) to create macro or other processing command that will add non-breaking space after single character in text mode?

Example:

```
A new example here will add a "tilde", after single letter, but will skip math mode.
$12 \times A = 128$
```

should produce:

```
A~new example here will add a~"tilde", after single letter, but will skip math mode.
$12 \times A = 128$
```

I know that I can use regular expresion like: `s/\(\<[a-z]\>\)[ ]/\1\~/g`, but this one will also change text in math mode and listing/verbatim mode.

Comment: This is a well known problem for Polish, Czech and Slovak, with their one letter prepositions.

Answer (score 4):

It would be a bit fragile to do that in TeX: I'd do the replace with a regex in the editor as you suggest. (If you just wanted to make a `~` in text and a normal space in math that would be easier, but having it work in listings and verbatim would be harder)

For example given

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

A new example here will add a "tilde", after single letter, but will skip math mode.
$12 \times A = 128$
\[ a b c = 123\]
and a bit nore text
\begin{align}
a &= b\\
x & = y 
\end{align}

\begin{verbatim}
A new example here will add a "tilde", after single letter,
but will skip math mode.
$12 \times A = 128$
\[ a b c = 123\]
and a bit nore text
\begin{align}
a &= b\\
x & = y 
\end{align}
\end{verbatim}


A new example here will add a "tilde", after single letter, but will skip math mode.
$12 \times A = 128$
\[ a b c = 123\]
and a bit nore text
\begin{align}
a &= b\\
x & = y 
\end{align}

\begin{verbatim}
A new example here will add a "tilde", after single letter,
but will skip math mode.
$12 \times A = 128$
\[ a b c = 123\]
and a bit nore text
\begin{align}
a &= b\\
x & = y 
\end{align}
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

The command `M-x addtilde` in emacs produces

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

A~new example here will add a~"tilde", after single letter, but will skip math mode.
$12 \times A = 128$
\[ a b c = 123\]
and a~bit nore text
\begin{align}
a &= b\\
x & = y 
\end{align}

\begin{verbatim}
A new example here will add a "tilde", after single letter,
but will skip math mode.
$12 \times A = 128$
\[ a b c = 123\]
and a bit nore text
\begin{align}
a &= b\\
x & = y 
\end{align}
\end{verbatim}


A~new example here will add a~"tilde", after single letter, but will skip math mode.
$12 \times A = 128$
\[ a b c = 123\]
and a~bit nore text
\begin{align}
a &= b\\
x & = y 
\end{align}

\begin{verbatim}
A new example here will add a "tilde", after single letter,
but will skip math mode.
$12 \times A = 128$
\[ a b c = 123\]
and a bit nore text
\begin{align}
a &= b\\
x & = y 
\end{align}
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

where `addtilde` is defined by

```
(defun hidespaceenv (e)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (re-search-forward 
      (if (string-equal e "[") "\\\\\\["
        (if (string-equal e "$") "\\$"
          (concat "\\\\begin{" e "}")))
      nil 1)
    (while (re-search-forward "\\([a-zA-Z]\\)\\(\\s-+\\)\\|\\(\\\\begin\\)" (save-excursion(re-search-forward 
                                  (if (string-equal e "[") "\\\\\\]"
                                    (if (string-equal e "$") "\\$"
                                      (concat "\\\\end{" e "}")))
                                  nil 1) (point)) 1)
      (replace-match "\\1SPACE@@\\2\\3@@" t))))

(defun addtilde ()
  (interactive)
  (mapcar `hidespaceenv (list "verbatim" "align" "equation" "[" "$"))
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (re-search-forward "\\(\\(^\\|\\s-+\\)[a-zA-Z]\\)\\s-+" nil 1)
    (replace-match "\\1~"))
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (re-search-forward "SPACE@@\\(\\s-+\\|\\\\begin\\)@@" nil 1)
    (replace-match "\\1")))
```

Comment: Thank you. I think that it's very close to final answer, but unfortunately, you can use lstlisting to create new listing environments, so I need to provide all environments that are type of verbatim/listing mode.

Comment: @faramir yes and other math environments such as align* or displaymath or ... (it also gets confused if you have comments like %\begin{align} but it is perhaps useful in real cases, even though it is easy to construct bad tests)

Comment: I wonder is it possible to use answer from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10033/environment-that-counts-words-inside to insert '~' after single letter tokens on text mode?

Comment: This. Function. Is. *Amazing.*  This is honestly the best idea I've ever seen as an editor macro.

Comment: @SeanAllred still waiting for the vim crowd to supply the vim version:-)