# newcommand to count words?

Tags: xetex, word-count

[Environment that counts words inside](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10033/environment-that-counts-words-inside/34572#34572) does like the title says, but prints the words that it counts, too. Is there a way to count the words without printing them?

```
\countCommand{Four and twenty blackbirds} % should print: 4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean counting the spaces in the argument, at all brace levels, with [`l3regex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3regex) you can do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\countwords}{+m} % allow \par (or blank lines in the argument)
 {
  \regex_count:nnN { \s } { #1 } \l_corneli_words_int
  \int_to_arabic:n { \l_corneli_words_int + 1 }
 }
\int_new:N \l_corneli_words_int
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\countwords{Four and twenty blackbirds}

\countwords{Four \emph{and twenty} blackbirds}
\end{document}
```

This prints

> 4
>   4

Comment: This seems the most robust so far for dealing with included LaTeX markup (environments, citations, hyperref).  It doesn't like paragraph breaks, but that seems like a minor point.

Comment: @JoeCorneli Without a complete specification it's difficult to do more. For allowing `\par`, just type `{+m}` instead of `{m}` in the definition of `\countwords`.

Comment: Cool!  OK, I think this answer wins the checkmark.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple solution using [`xstring`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/xstring)

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\wordcount}[1]{\StrCount{#1}{\space}[\tmp]%
\number\numexpr\tmp+1\relax}
\begin{document}

\wordcount{Four and twenty blackbirds}
\end{document}
```

It works by counting the spaces, and then adding `1`; it works fine even when there are multiple spaces between words, so you can use

```
\wordcount{Four    and     twenty     blackbirds}
```

and still get `4`. *However* if you try anything like

```
\wordcount{ Four and twenty blackbirds}
\wordcount{Four and twenty blackbirds }
\wordcount{ Four and twenty blackbirds }
```

then you won't get the expected result. You can fix this using, for example, something like the following:

```
\newcount\cmh
\newcommand{\wordcount}[1]{%
\StrCount{#1}{\space}[\tmp]%
\cmh=\tmp%
\IfBeginWith{#1}{\space}{\advance\cmh by -1\relax}{}%
\IfEndWith{#1}{\space}{\advance\cmh by -1\relax}{}%
\number\numexpr\cmh+1\relax
}
```

Comment: ah, \space - that's helpful!  Very useful piece of information that :-)

Comment: @JoeCorneli glad it helped ;) it works fine with multiple spaces between words, too!

Comment: ... and newlines too!  Impressed!

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\begin{document}
\getargsC{Four and twenty blackbirds}
Words = \narg\par
The words are \argi, \argii, \argiii, and \argiv.
\end{document}
```

Thus, based on this MWE, `\def\wordcount#1{\getargsC{#1}\narg}` would suffice to answer the OP's question.  Note that `\getargsC` is functionally equivalent but far superior in speed to the `\getargs` macro of the `stringstrings` package.

Comment: This one has the benefit of being more robust vis a vis hyperref, although neither this answer nor the other one are working with things like quoting environments.  Indeed, \wordcount{\emph{Four and twenty blackbirds}} gives 1 as the answer.

Comment: @JoeCorneli Indeed, `\emph{...}` is treated as a single word, precisely because that is the way LaTeX treats groups (think about how we define arguments); however, `\itshape four and twenty blackbirds` would pickup the proper number of words.